# Reload fragment using Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the navigation component to load my fragments like given here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

```
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_opt1,
                R.id.navigation_opt2,
                R.id.navigation_opt3,
                R.id.navigation_more
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

I also have a `Toolbar` at the top with a Spinner. I want to reload/refresh the `fragment` & its view model when the `spinner` item is selected. I tried the below code for reloading but it isn't working. Also, I know we should not be using `fragmentManager` in Navigation Component

```
val ftr: FragmentTransaction = requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        ftr.detach(this).attach(this).commit()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sorry for late reply. I am using below code for the same scenario.
That might help. call this method in your spinner ItemClick.
we have to use popbackstack for avoid adding same fragment again and again.

```
  private fun refreshCurrentFragment(){
        val id = navController.currentDestination?.id
        navController.popBackStack(id!!,true)
        navController.navigate(id)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes above answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171678/12748481) is right

if you want to reload/refresh you current fragment after perform specific operation
you have to destroy this current fragment and navigate here again

```
val fragmentId = findNavController().currentDestination?.id
findNavController().popBackStack(fragmentId!!,true)
findNavController().navigate(fragmentId)
```